# How do I improve the ebony blade

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

It is of an deleted quest and I can't improve it also is it somehow involved with boethia?

Comment: Sorry for the double question

Comment: I'll throw you an upvote since you're new and the question is reasonably well-written. You're not going to get many, as this question shows a lack of research. Put "ebony blade" in google, and you will probably see the page all the information in the answer came from as the top result.

Answer (score 6):

The Ebony Blade is Mephala's Daedric artifact. It is not connected to Boethia (whose artifact is the Ebony Mail).

The Ebony Blade cannot be improved by smithing. This is possibly explained in Admonition Against Ebony which states that: "Not even the hottest fires of the Skyforge could melt it; indeed the coals themselves seemed to cool when it was placed within," revealing the sword's immunity to heat or normal forging/smithing techniques.

The sword's enchantment can be improved, however, by killing friendly characters. This includes followers and anyone for whom the dovahkiin has completed a quest or favour.

Source: http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Ebony_Blade_(Skyrim)